# Highlighting a div when anchor is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, onclick

I found myself stuck with this:

I have an anchor link that points to an `<a>` inside a `div`, so the page scrolls all the way down to it.

Unfortunately, the `div` is at the bottom of the page, so usermost likely won't see it.

I thought a good way to solve this would be changing the class of the div when the link is clicked, for example switching the border color to red and then fade back to normal in 2 seconds.

I have no clue on how to do this. I Googled around and it seems this can be done with jQuery, but I really don't understand how to edit the scripts to my needs.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's difficult to tell why  McGarnagle, Praveen Kumar, undefined, Macmade, Graviton can't read and understand this perfectly clear question.  Are they qualified to have close rights when they can't understand very basic questions about HTML?  This most certainly is a real question, and anyone who has worked with HTML (and also cares about user experience) has most likely run into this problem.  The browser can't scroll up to put the target of an in-page link at the top of the page when there isn't enough content beneath it.  Very very simple.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can do the **Yellow Fade Trick** in two ways:

#### Using the `:target` pseudo class:

```
<section id="voters"> 
   Content
</section>
```

Respective **CSS**

```
:target {
   background: yellow;
}
```

#### Using Yellow Fade Technique

In the click function, if you have, you can do this way:

```
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function(){
    $($(this).attr("href")).effect("highlight", {}, 1500);
});
```

Or using `animate()`:

```
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function(){
    $($(this).attr("href")).animate({"background-color": "#ffc"}).delay(2000).animate({"background-color": "transparent"});
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HnERh/

***PS:** For using* `effect()`*, You need to have these two JS:* `effects.core.js` *and* `effects.highlight.js`*.*

Comment: Are you sure `animate` works without jquery UI? See [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp)

Comment: The `animate` approach doesn't work for me. I am not using jQuery UI (just jQuery).

Answer (score 10):

## Three choices:

### First one - CSS3

Use this method if you don't really care about [supporting all browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-animation). It's pure CSS, so that's an advantage. Here's an outline (includes multiple versions of rules for multiple browsers):

```
.youranchorsclass:active ~ #yourdivsid { /*when the anchor is active (clicked)*/
   -moz-animation: myanimation 1s;
   -webkit-animation: myanimation 1s;
   -o-animation: myanimation 1s;
   animation: myanimation 1s;
}
@-moz-keyframes myanimation, @-webkit-keyframes myanimation, @-o-keyframes myanimation, @keyframes myanimation {
   from { background: red; }
   to { background: white; /*or whatever it was originally*/ }
}
```

(If you want to get rid of all those ugly prefixed rules, take a look at [PrefixFree](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/)).

### Second one - jQuery

Use this if you do care about older-browsers support. Include jQuery in your page, to start with, by inserting this into your `head`:

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

Then:

```
$(".yourlink").click(function() {
   $("#yourdivid").css("background", "red").delay(1000).css("background", "white");
};
```

Note that this jQuery method doesn't gradually change the color, you'd have to include a plugin (such as [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com)) to do so.

### Third one - pure JavaScript

Use this if you don't want to include a relatively-huge library just for such a small effect. It's pretty straightforward, here's a commented outline to get you started:

```
function changeDivColor(color) {
    document.getElementById("yourdivid").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
document.getElementById("youranchor").onClick = function() { //when the anchor is clicked
    changeDivColor("red"); //chang the div color to red
    setTimeout(function() { //wait 1000 milliseconds (1s) -- see below
        changeDivColor("white"); //then change it back to white
    }, 1000);
};
```

Hope that helped in any manner!

Comment: I see your second option uses .css property. Good point about animation, I didn't know that.

Comment: The pure CSS solution (first) is great. The tilde (~) did not work for me - could use `:target` instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65716121/1526703) answer.

Answer (score 2):

On clicking you can change the colour of the div to red `.css({ elements })`,
then wait 2 seconds `.delay( time )`
and animate back to the original colour `.animate({ elements }, time, callback)`

```
$(document).ready() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
        $('div.divs_class_or_id_name').css('border','solid 1px #ff0000').delay(2000).animate({
            border: 'solid 1px #000000'
        }, 500, function() {
            // animation complete
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to the following.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#element").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    $("#element").animate({
        "background-color": "#FFFFCC"
    }).delay(2000).animate({
        "background-color": "#00FFFF" //original background color
    });
});
```

Make sure to include a jquery plugin that allows the animation of colors, such as http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors-min.js.

Although @praveen-kumar's `:target` solution seems nice, you could do it purely with a css3 animation I believe.

Comment: @Abody97 By plugin you mean jquery ? The question has jquery tag!

Comment: @Ashkan No, jQuery can't do color animations without a plugin.

Comment: how about $(...).css({"background-color": "#FFFFCC"}) ??

Comment: @Abody97 I've updated my post, though I admit my answer isn't the best here, nice to have options.

Answer (score 1):

@Chris' pure CSS solution is great. The `~` did not work for me (probably it works with [siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) only)

Here is a variant that is tested and works in 2021:

```
#targetdivid:target { /* i.e when this element is navigated to (from a link) */
   animation-name: ref-animation;
   animation-duration: 3s;
}
@keyframes ref-animation {
   from { background-color: #FFFFCC;     }  /* light yellow */
   to   { background-color: transparent; }  /* assuming original was transparent */
}
```